# when executing f2py fib1.f -m fib2 -h fib1.pyf I get the following error File " ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using `Mac 10.9` and running `Python 2.7.8`. Currently I am trying to use `f2py`. I follow the example in the guide and typed

```
$ f2py -c fib1.f -m fib1
```

and I receive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/f2py", line 3, in <module>
    import f2py2e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/f2py2e/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import f2py2e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/f2py2e/f2py2e.py", line 26, in <module>
    import crackfortran
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/f2py2e/crackfortran.py", line 1586
    as=b['args']
```

I have tried as well the following command

```
$ f2py -c --help-fcompiler
```

and I receive the as error as above. I hope someone can help me.
Regards

Comment: This isn't the whole traceback. Can you make sure the last line that specifies the type of exception is included?

Comment: thess are the last two lines:
    as=b['args']
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 3):

`as` is a reserved keyword in Python 2.6+.

Therefore trying to assign to it like this

```
as=b['args']
```

is a syntax error.

It's used in [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) (context managers).

In Python 2.5 you already get a deprecation warning if you're using it:

```
>>> as='foo'
<stdin>:1: Warning: 'as' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
```

So that's some *really* old code you're trying to run. You've basically got two options:

- Use Python 2.5 or 2.4 to run it
- Or fix the code and replace the variable `as` with something else.

Comment: It looks like they are using Mac's system python.  They will get better mileage if they switch to [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and use that python.

Comment: I have replaced "as" with "a_s", but didn't solve the problem. Now I got:File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/f2py", line 4, in <module>
    f2py2e.main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/f2py2e/f2py2e.py", line 677, in main
    run_compile()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/f2py2e/f2py2e.py", line 625, in run_compile
    raise ImportError,'Must have Numeric installed.'
ImportError: Must have Numeric installed.

Comment: I am using the latest release of both numpy and python. I have tried it on Windows 7 and still have the same problem.

Comment: Sure, it did solve the problem your question was about (the syntax error). This is an entirely different problem (a missing dependency, `Numeric`).

Comment: And as I pointed out, it's `f2py` that's too old. If anything, you should be using an *older* version of Python, or a newer version of `f2py` if there is one.

Comment: the F2py comes with numpy.1.8.2.2 which is the latest release, thus F2py should be the latest as it part of numpy